# Unable to install Windows 8.1 using Apple Boot Camp

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, boot-camp, imac

I've been tirelessly searching a answer to my issue, but I couldn't find anything.

I'm trying to install Windows 8.1 on a mid-2010 21.5" iMac running on macOS High Sierra (10.13.6).

I have a 16Gb USB drive connected that I used to download the Windows 8.1 installation pack. However, when trying to install the OS (I checked the "Install Windows 7 or Windows 8" option on Boot Camp), I always have the same error : `Installation disk not found`

I tried many times to wipe out the USB drive, to start the whole downloading again, but every time I try to install, I have the same issue. Please note that I have also the ISO file of Windows 8.1.

Can anyone help me ?

Comment: Did you let Boot Camp Assistant format the disk for you?

Comment: I previously formatted the USB drive in MS-DOS (FAT) with Master Boot Record

Comment: Try to do it with Boot Camp Assistant.

Comment: I tried to download again, but I got the same error

Comment: Does your computer have a DVD reader & writer?

Comment: The iMac I use have one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Apple Forum has this answer in the post
[Installation disk not found (Bootcamp)](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8419137):

> On a 2011 Mac, you need a physical DVD and fully functional built-in
> Optical drive (external CD/DVD drives do not work) to install Windows.
> If you have an ISO, you can burn it to a blank DVD-R SL (of a
> reputable brand) by right-clicking on ISO, and expanding the Burn box
> to look like
>
> [image]
>
> Use the lowest burn rate to avoid block errors.

Comment: I've burnt a DVD, but I have a new error : "Windows 10 is not supported on this Mac". It is strange as I downloaded the good support software on my USB key, and as I burnt the good ISO file (8.1) on the DVD

Comment: My problem was fixed ! I think the disk wasn't read correctly !